# ExpandableListView onGroupLongClick

Tags: android, expandablelistview

How can i implement an onGroupLongClickListener?
If i use onItemLongClick then i just get the position of the element seen by the listview, so i need to convert this position to groupposition and childposition

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getExpandableListPosition() this function converts it